# jQuery Bootstrap ScrollSpy doesn't work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying the ScrollSpy Bootstrap plugin, but it's not working properly. See the code below, it always highlight the last item.

http://jsfiddle.net/bRYMC/

```
<nav id="navbar">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page5">Page 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div data-spy="scroll">
  <section id="page1" class="page">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="page2" class="page">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="page3" class="page">
    <h1>Page 3</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="page4" class="page">
    <h1>Page 4</h1>
  </section>

  <section id="page5" class="page">
    <h1>Page 5</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

​Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `data-spy="scroll"` on the body tag and it should work. Please check the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRYMC/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Set `data-target="#navbar"` next to your`data-spy="scroll"` tag to see if that works.